# Cutting off continuous paper Brother QL-710W label printer

Tags: objective-c, airprint

When I print the machine start spooling out : does not cut off at all.

I have set textFormatter.maximumContentWidth and Height to no avail.

Any ideas on how to force the device to cut off the label at a specific size?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, found it : printInteractionController:cutLengthForPaper